# I needed to use bootstrap with angular2 so when I ran the command

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I needed to use bootstrap with angular2 so when I ran the command

```
$ npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

I had this:

```
 angular2-quickstart@1.0.0    C:\Users\alaaeddine\Downloads\Compressed\app3\angular2-seed
 +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@^2.0.0
 +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@^2.0.0
 +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/forms@^2.0.0
`    -- @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.16

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0  (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.16 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.16 requires a peer of @angular/common@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@1.0.0-alpha.16 requires a peer of @angular/forms@^2.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
```

Comment: hey can you please tell me if error persists after applying updated versions? otherwise, is there a new error you can provide?

Answer (score 1):

Edit your `package.json` to have following versions:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.0"

    // might want to update this ones as to match actual github version of angular quickstart
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.2.4",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
```

Tnen `npm install` and you should be fine

If you are just begining with your project I recomend pulling the changes from the [repo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart)

Comment: I have this problem as well, only that for me it says that it requires 4.0.3 version of those angular main components. I just pulled down this project that I did earlier and not it won't run because of this. Modified my package file as described but still the same issue. Should I open a new question?

Comment: for this ng-bootstrap problem I got the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43715112/angular2-how-to-downgrade-ng-bootstrap?rq=1