# Angular2 How to downgrade ng-bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Hi I am currently using ng-bootstrap  from the link below

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

But since this latest version of ng-bootstrap has dependencies of Angular4,

I am getting bunch of bootstrap errors that i didn't get before.

Is there any way where I can avoid updating to Angular4 and downgrade ng-bootstrap that could suuport angular2.

I've already used many of these bootstrap so i can't go through changing the bootstrap

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Officially, it said it has been test with Angular 4.0.3. I guess you may not downgrade it but you still can try. https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at their [changelog](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md), I would say you can go back to 1.0.0-alpha.24 (2017-04-22) version, since they explicit mention that now alpha.25 requires a minimal version of Angular 4.0.3